# Validation message won't appear - accepts 'please select' as an entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, enums, html-select

I am submiting a blank form and all of the other fields display their correct validation error message stating that the field cannot be empty, except for one.

Here is the model:

```
public enum Medium
{
    [Description("Teleconference & Report")]
    Teleconference_Report,
    [Description("Email & Telephone")]
    Email_Telephone
}

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Medium")]
public Medium Medium { get; set; }
```

Here is the field in the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Medium, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.DropDownList("MediumID", null, "Please select...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Medium, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The "MediumID" DropDownList is populated using a viewbag which is set to whatever the following returns:

```
// Puts all of the mediums of communication into a user friendly dropdownlist.
public List<SelectListItem> GetMediumList()
{
    List<SelectListItem> mediumList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (Medium state in EnumToList<Medium>())
    {
        mediumList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = GetEnumDescription(state),
            Value = state.ToString(),
        });
    }

    return mediumList;
}
```

The issue is, is that when the default display of the drop down list of 'please select...' is left, this is accepted and the form gets submitted, which doesn't happen for any of my other fields. When looking at the new entry in the database, the 'Medium' field gets set to the first thing in the DropDownList which is 'Teleconference & Report'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Below shows the form section for another enum called 'Frequency', but these are not changed to user friendly strings.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Frequency, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Frequency, "Please select...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Frequency, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Below here, shows the two methods which turn the enums into user friendly strings:

```
// Returns a 'user friendly', readable version of the enum.
public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
        return attributes[0].Description;
    else
        return value.ToString();
}

// Puts all of the same enums into a list.
public static IEnumerable<T> EnumToList<T>()
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);

    // Can't use generic type constraints on value types,
    // so have to do check like this.
    if (enumType.BaseType != typeof(Enum))
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be of type System.Enum");

    Array enumValArray = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
    List<T> enumValList = new List<T>(enumValArray.Length);

    foreach (int val in enumValArray)
    {
        enumValList.Add((T)Enum.Parse(enumType, val.ToString()));
    }

    return enumValList;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your action method once

Comment: @Rahul I can't think of a way of showing it without giving away confidential information. I have a GET Create() and a POST Create(). In the GET I have the following code: ViewBag.MediumID = GetMediumList(); and this is also in the POST, if it fails. The MediumID is contained within a bind within the parameters. The other information also isn't relevant or wouldn't help I don't think.

Comment: @Coulton It is passed to the form using a ViewBag (see above comment). This part works because the DropDownList does populate and works when you select one. It just doesn't display the model error message when please select is highlighted even though it is set to 'Required' in the model and the 'please select' is not an entry/enum but a default option.

Answer (score 0):

Add the EnumDataType attribute to the property on your view model:

```
[EnumDataType(typeof(Medium), ErrorMessage = "Submitted value is not valid for the enum")]
public Medium Medium { get; set; }
```

You should add this anyway, because an Enum can represent any numeric value and won't be validated automatically by the MVC framework.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have added this to my model and it still doesn't display the message. Do I need to change anything in my view by here: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Medium, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) so that this error message displays instead? Or did I need to remove [Required] from the model at all?

Comment: I'm just doing some experimentation in VS.  I'll report back soon :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your time. Here's a link to a screenshot of what's happening: http://i.snag.gy/mnPXU.jpg. Might make it clearer.

Comment: Strange, I just created a project with similar code.  An enum with a `[Required]` on it and it worked straight away

Comment: I'll show you the frequency form part anyway, might help as they are slightly different. The frequency form part uses an EnumDropDownList whereas the Medium uses a normal DropDownList which is passed using a ViewBag called 'MediumID'. The reason they are different is because I have made a new list of 'user friendly' enums using the description tag, which is where I think the problem lies. I'll also add the methods which make this user friendly list to the original post now.

Comment: Think I might be getting closer to the root of the problem (but perhaps not). When I switched the DropDownList to that of an enum. The field automatically populated to the first enum and not to the 'please select...' default option, but I can't figure out why. In fact, even when I try to edit this field for another entry, it always defaults back to the first enum - oh dear! This is definitely the issue, it doesn't display the validation message because it is techincally valid cause it defaults to an enum!